# Twitter Bootstrap Responsive Navbar Broken on Small Screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, responsive-design

I've been reading the docs and comparing my code to Bootstrap's examples, but I cannot figure out why the navbar on my site drops down about 100px when I make my browser window smaller or view it on a phone.

http://warm-ocean-8133.herokuapp.com/

Here's my html in jade template format.

```
.navbar.navbar-fixed-top
  .navbar-inner
    .container
      a.btn.btn-navbar(data-toggle="collapse",data-target=".nav-collapse")
        span.icon-bar
        span.icon-bar
        span.icon-bar
      a.brand(href='#home') Miles Matthias
      .nav-collapse
        ul.nav
          li.active
            a(href='#home') Home
          li
            a(href='#contact') Contact
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The visual anomaly appears because you defined the top padding for the `body` element *after* including the `bootstrap-responsive.css` file, which means that the "responsive" styles are unable to override your padding:

```html
<link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- ... some stuff -->
<style type="text/css">body {padding-top: 60px;}</style>
```

You want the padding to be used when the page is displayed at full width (so that your main content doesn't get displayed underneath the top navbar), but you want the "responsive" styles to override that padding when you shrink the browser width (or display the page on a mobile device).

So the fix is simple: **define the top padding for the `body` element *between* your inclusion of `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap-responsive.css`**.

[The Bootstrap samples](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples.html) are a great template to use to get started. The [fluid layout](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html) site does it like this:

```
<!-- Le styles -->
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
  .sidebar-nav {
    padding: 9px 0;
  }
</style>
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I used the basic Bootstrap example which already does this, but it still didn't solve my problem. The method below works.

Comment: If you use the customize tool on the Bootstrap site to obtain the entire package, then this already includes the responsive sections too, making it impossible to insert the padding instructions between the main and responsive sections. Or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 23):

You can use **@media** to **override** the body padding.
Like this:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 979px) {
    body {
      padding-top: 0;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: In my opinion this one is the better solution (over that one provided in the twitter bootstrap examples) since it clearly separates own styles from the bootstrap/responsive foundation.

Comment: `@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }`