# Twitter Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top small screen fix for Meteor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I am having a problem as described in this post:

[Twitter Bootstrap Responsive Navbar Broken on Small Screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185384/twitter-bootstrap-responsive-navbar-broken-on-small-screens)

I am unsure how to fix this in Meteor though, because Meteor seems to do all of that under the hood...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this question interesting enough to figure out some solutions plus gathering some basic thoughts on this problem.

Meteor states in its' documentation that applications should be written *such a way that it is insensitive to the order in which files are loaded* (see [Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#concepts)) . While this is (ideally) a good paradigm for designing and loading javascript modules and dependencies, it raises questions on how to do-it-best when defining user styles on top of a foundation like *bootstrap*.

In fact *order matters* when it comes to css in that way *that specific styles should override default styles*.  With smart packages like Meteors *bootstrap* package the loading order of `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap_responsive.css` directly one after another is fixedly defined. Thus said, putting something between it "on-the-fly" is impossible.

**Recommended solution: Override on top of boostrap/responsive**:

In my opinion best practice is do define and load user styles that way that they work like desired when loading *after* all of the foundation files. An example:

*bootstrap-user.css*:

```
@media (min-width: 980px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
}
```

Put this into one of your user css files and everything should be fine. User css files in your project root are *always* loaded after smart package files like those linked by the bootstrap package.

**Well, here's the "inter-style" approach**

If you nevertheless want to hack it in that way like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185384/twitter-bootstrap-responsive-navbar-broken-on-small-screens) (and even twitter itself suggests) you can go and write your own *smart package*:

*package.js*:

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "UX/UI framework from Twitter - My variant"
});

Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.add_files('css/bootstrap.css', 'client');
  api.add_files('css/bootstrap-pre-responsive.css', 'client');
  api.add_files('css/bootstrap-responsive.css', 'client');
  ...
  // More resource definitions like glyphicons-halflings go here
  ...
}
```

While the package file *css/bootstrap-pre-responsive.css* contains:

```
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Alternatively you can skip using a smart package for bootstrap integration and instead let just let Meteor collect and load your project resources - the conventions for load order within your project root is described within the concepts section of the Meteor doc. But: This would mean naming files in an alphabetical way that reflects desired order! (not very elegant)

However, I personally don't like the way of solving the problem like described the latter way.

Last but not least: Of course it's sometimes the best way to build and compile an own boostrap variant with all desired styles minified to one file.